# Hive rolling sum of data over date

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am working on Hive and am facing an issue with rolling counts. The sample data I am working on is as shown below:

[image]

and the output I am expecting is as shown below:

[image]

I tried using the following query but it is not returning  the rolling count:

```
select event_dt,status, count(distinct account) from
(select *, row_number() over (partition by account order by event_dt 
desc) 
as rnum from table.A 
where event_dt between '2018-05-02' and '2018-05-04') x where rnum =1 
group by event_dt, status;
```

Please help me with this if some one has solved a similar issue.

Comment: Actually, I can't figure out how those summary numbers come from that data.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Basically if you see for date 05/02 there is A1 A2 and A3 who registered but A2 also moved to active state which means A1 and A3 only are registered but A2 is active so registered acct count is A1 & A3 = 2 and A2 which is 1 account is shown in active state. Next day 3 accts A4,5,6 are added, A4 is active on same date which means 1 is added to active state but A2 is suspended so we reduce one from active state and add to suspended so A5,A6,A1,A3 remain in registerd A4 in active and A2 in suspended.

Comment: . . There is a problem with your description.  The dates are all the same and there is no other column that specifies the ordering.  How do you know the order of the actions?  Remember:  SQL tables have no ordering, so this information must be in a column.

Comment: Oh ok .. I am sorry I am generating this data from another table and I converetd the time stamp to date. I missed mentioning this information in the question above. So if we have a timestamp how will the solution look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to just want conditional aggregation:

```
select event_dt,
       sum(case when status = 'Registered' then 1 else 0 end) as registered,
       sum(case when status = 'active_acct' then 1 else 0 end) as active_acct,
       sum(case when status = 'suspended' then 1 else 0 end) as suspended,
       sum(case when status = 'reactive' then 1 else 0 end) as reactive
from table.A 
group by event_dt
order by event_dt;
```

EDIT:

This is a tricky problem.  The solution I've come up with does a cross-product of dates and users and then calculates the most recent status as of each date.

So:

```
select a.event_dt,
       sum(case when aa.status = 'Registered' then 1 else 0 end) as registered,
       sum(case when aa.status = 'active_acct' then 1 else 0 end) as active_acct,
       sum(case when aa.status = 'suspended' then 1 else 0 end) as suspended,
       sum(case when aa.status = 'reactive' then 1 else 0 end) as reactive
from (select d.event_dt, ac.account, a.status,
             max(case when a.status is not null then a.timestamp end) over (partition by ac.account order by d.event_dt) as last_status_timestamp
      from (select distinct event_dt from table.A) d cross join
           (select distinct account from table.A) ac left join
           (select a.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by account, event_dt order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
            from table.A a
           ) a
           on a.event_dt = d.event_dt and
              a.account = ac.account and
              a.seqnum = 1  -- get the last one on the date
     ) a left join
     table.A aa
     on aa.timestamp = a.last_status_timestamp and
        aa.account = a.account
group by d.event_dt
order by d.event_dt;
```

What this is doing is creating a derived table with rows for all accounts and dates.  This has the status on certain days, but not all days.

The cumulative max for `last_status_timestamp` calculates the most recent timestamp that has a valid status.  This is then joined back to the table to get the status on that date.  Voila!  This is the status used for the conditional aggregation.

The cumulative max and join is a work-around because Hive does not (yet?) support the `ignore nulls` option in `lag()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs, they were very helpful, I have got a solution using them.